# Fit entire screen (bottom and status bar) ViewPager

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am having trouble in filling entire screen with my background. I have my main_activity with green background to check if it fills entire screen and it works. The main activity properly fills entire screen as I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        />
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"/-->

<com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.WormDotsIndicator
        android:id="@+id/pager_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:dotsColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:dotsStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:dotsCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:dotsSize="16dp"
        app:dotsSpacing="4dp"
        app:progressMode="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now I have my fragment with orange background. I have set width and height to match parent and also fitSystemWindows, same as in main activity, but it doesnt fit 100% - status bar and bottom bar are unaffected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/pantry_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:text="@string/fragment_pantry"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The effect is visible on screen below. I tried a simple workaround with negative margins but I am afraid of how it will work on other devices.

PS: Phone has notch ... doubt that has anything to do with it.

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom|center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Setting view pager to fill parent did not work - unless there is some othere change here that I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code in your Activity on before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
>                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);